# Are poisons that you apply to weapons instanteneous?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Let's say that I have a Bow with is enchanted with Frost.
Now I take a Weakness to Frost/Ice x% potion and poison the bow.

I shoot at an unsuspecting Skeever and hit it.

Does the potion-weakness go into effect fast enough that the poor Skeever get the extra damage from the weakness of the arrow that just hit it.

Same question of course for Fire and Lightning.

Comment: No Skeevers were hurt in the writing of this Question

Comment: In Oblivion the answer is "no": weakness effects don't help the same hit they get applied in. I would not be surprised if Skyrim is the same, but I don't actually know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sound too good for me. As I found on [usep.net](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Weakness_to_Poison)

> Weakness to Poison **has to be applied prior** to a dose of poison for the
>   weakness **to take effect**. For example, if the enemy is not weakened and
>   **you use a poison with Weakness to Poison and damage**, **the damage will
>   not be affected by the weakness that time** but the enemy will be
>   affected in later uses of the poison.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily apply to other weaknesses.

Comment: Why developers should differ weakness to posion with every other?

Comment: I think this is more of an issue of in what order different types of damage and effects are applied - if poison is applied before enchantments it'll work, otherwise it won't. Poison with a weakness to poison is a different subset of the problem.

Comment: @kotekzot No, all weapon effects are all applied simultaneously. The engine doesn't make a significant distinction between poison damage (including elemental "poison") and enchantment damage either. (They're merely different ways to apply the same Magic Effect Record's contents.)